# Path management for multiple toolchains?

Tags: windows, path

So the story is probably one that more skilled developers than I run into:

Ug...Windows development. Multiple development tool chains (MinGW, VC2010, VC2008). PATH can't get too big. Annoying. DLL hell with different tool chains. Separate build & install for different libraries (boostVC2008, boostVC2010, boostMinGW, ect). Name conflicts and PATH overflow.

My (current planned) solution: separate cmd windows for each that set the variables correctly. Is there any standard way?

Comment: `set path` in a series of batch files?

Comment: @techie007 thats my current plan, though you'd think this'd be a common enough thing that there would be a better way...

Comment: What's 'common' for a developer is definitely not common for regular users. :)